Homepage anchor links don't work from other pages, and menu items remain active when using full URLs in WordPress
I have a question about a wordpress site I am trying to build, but I am kind of an amateur with this xd
When I view my 'terms and conditions' page and click on a menu item in my header, I don't navigate to the corresponding position on my homepage, even though I have anchor links set up for that. I tried adding the full site URLs in the menu within WordPress, but then the menu items in my header on the homepage remain constantly active (they turn yellow).
Could you help solve this issue without coding because i'm such an amateur in coding? Thank you in advance!
I tried adding the full site URLs in the menu within WordPress, but then the menu items in my header on the homepage remain constantly active (they turn yellow).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
